# Maven plugin management add dependency only to a specific execution

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want to add a specific dependency only when maven-dependency-plugin executes a specific execution.

For example, if I add a section in parent pom like this:

```
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>myExecution</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
            <version>${myVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Pom for Child1:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Pom for Child2:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>myExecution</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Pom for Child3:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>anotherExecution</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My desired behaviour for these three child projects are:

1. Child1 does not depend on 'myArtifact'
2. Child2 depends on 'myArtifact'
3. Child3 does not depend on 'myArtifact'

In my current codebase, this dependency is repeated in a lot of pom files which uses that specific execution.

I wonder if there is an easier and minimum effect solution for this behaviour.

Comment: First this path is simply wrong, cause adding a dependency conditionally sounds wrong..The question is why do you like to do that and what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: We need a specific zip file for a specific execution in maven-dependency-plugin. Currently that zip file is added as a dependency repeatedly to each child pom file when that execution is declared. Since we have dozens of child poms, I want to delete all the unnecessary repetitions. However, I do not want to make that zip a general dependency for maven-dependency-plugin, because it is only necessary for that specific execution.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. A zip file is needed for the execution of maven-dependency-plugin is simply wrong cause maven-dependency-plugin should usually never necessary in a usual build. The question is what purpose the zip file has and what it contains?

Comment: We are trying to switch to parallel builds on our build server. Maven 3.0.2 is used on the server. When testing parallel builds, we get the following error from maven-dependency-plugin: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:unpack (<id of unpack execution>) on project <project name>: Unable to find artifact. Could not find artifact <group name>:<artifact id>:zip:<classifier>:<version> in repo. We have added the required zip as a dependency for this specific execution in maven-dependency-plugin, however it is a repetition hell.

Comment: First if you are using Maven 3.0.2 is simply really bad cause Maven 3.0.2 has many bugs..upgrade as ap to Maven 3.5.3...furthermore if you have things like `unpack` in your build I assume there things going wrong...Furthermore the errors shows that you have not defined the dependencies between the modules correctly....